# Java properties files OR public static variables within a certain class OR both?

Tags: java, properties, global-variables

I wonder if it is good practice to store some global variables such as:
THREAD_PER_CORE (to determine how many threads I should have in my thread pools)
WAIT_DELETE_MESSAGE (to determine how long a message should last)

in a .properties file.

Or should I use a class in which these are defined as global public static variables instead

Or should I do both and get read these properties files to store them within that class as public static variables afterwards

Or maybe I should set everything as environment variables instead...

And if you have any other recommendations, I'm open to anything... I could listen

All could work, I just wonder which one is conventionally more acceptable

Thank you :)

Comment: Depends on how flexible you want the program to be - what you want to the user to be able to configure.

Comment: I've already given two examples.. I want these variables to be easy to configure, and I want the code to look clean. So i could say that my current inclination is to create a class called 'Global' and define all these things as public static variables which are all initialized with the properties file the moment the resp. class is constructed via my PSVM.